# como utilizar sublime text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no he podido correr mi codigo, solo me sale [finished in 0.1s].
soy nuevo en programcion y estoy utilizando python. que me hace falta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicolas, primero debes configurar el Sublime Text para poder ejecutar el código Python..

Has lo siguiente.. En el Sublime Text:

1- Vas a Preferences > KeyBindings.

2 En el lado derecho, en la parte Keymap-User vas a colocar lo siguiente:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
{
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}}
```

Toma en cuenta que la combinación de teclas que se encuentra entre los corchetes [] es la que vas a usar para ejecutar el código.

Has la prueba y nos cuentas como te fue.

Comment: hola iflores2000, gracias por responder mi pregunta. intente hacerlo como tu me muestras y no, sigue igual, escribo mi codigo hello world. y lo que aparace en la consola es [Finished in 0.1s], y no me aparece hello world. sigue lo mismo. espero tu ayuda. gracias

Comment: y qué código estas colocando?? porque si hiciste los pasos correctamente en el KeyBindings, no deberías tener problemas (revisa bien eso)... Comparte el código para poder ayudarte, para descartar que sea ahí donde tengas el problema...